# How to maintain millisecond to convert string into datatime?

Tags: r

```
$ TZ=America/New_York R
R> as.POSIXct('2022-01-21 19:55:26.926')
[1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26 EST"
```

The above code loses millisecond info. Is there a way to maintain millisecond info during the conversion?

Comment: `as.POSIXct('2022-01-21 19:55:26.926') %>% 
  format(., "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")`

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR:

Fractional seconds *are* preserved in the `as.POSIXct` result, but not printed by default. If you want `print` output with fractional seconds, then you have two options:

- Use `format` to coerce the `POSIXct` object to a string containing the decimal and digits after it, and print the string.

  ```r
  x <- "2022-01-21 19:55:26.926"
  y <- as.POSIXct(x)
  format(y, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3 %Z")
  ## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26.926 EST"
  ```
- Set the global option `digits.secs`, and print the `POSIXclt` object.

  ```
  options(digits.secs = 3L)
  y
  ## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26.926 EST"
  ```

---

If you debug into `as.POSIXct(x)`, where `x` is a character vector, then you'll find this sequence of calls:

```
as.POSIXct(x)
 \_ as.POSIXct.default(x)
     \_ as.POSIXlt(x)
         \_ as.POSIXlt.character(x, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", "%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d"))
             \_ strptime(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

`strptime`, according to its `format` argument, does the actual work of extracting date-time information (year, month, day, etc.; see `?POSIXlt`) from `x`. Since you don't specify a format in the `as.POSIXct` call, the first format tried is `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"`, which happens to match your string (see `?strptime`). The important component is `%OS`, about which `?strptime` says:

> Further, for `strptime` `%OS` will input seconds including fractional seconds.

Let's verify that sub-second digits are preserved by `strptime` and, in turn, by `as.POSIXct`:

```r
# Print numbers with as much precision as possible
options(digits = 22L)

x <- "2022-01-21 19:55:26.123456789"
strptime(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")$sec
## [1] 26.12345678899999867895
y <- as.POSIXct(x)
as.numeric(y)
## [1] 1642812926.123456716537
```

The `strptime` result is not exact but is accurate to the least significant digit of the input, which is perhaps all we can expect. The `as.POSIXct` result is accurate to within a microsecond, which is all that `?POSIXct` guarantees:

> Classes `"POSIXct"` and `"POSIXlt"` are able to express fractions of a second.  (Conversion of fractions between the two forms may not be exact, but will have better than microsecond accuracy.)

In any case, it is clear that sub-second digits *are* preserved by `as.POSIXct`. Your suggestion that they *aren't* stems from the fact that, by default, `POSIXct` objects are printed with seconds rounded to the nearest integer:

```r
y
## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26 EST"
```

One way around this behaviour is to use `format` to coerce the `POSIXct` object to character, specifying a format for the resulting strings that includes sub-second digits. `%OS` and `%OSn` (but not `%S`) can be used here. From `?strftime`:

> Specific to R is `%OSn`, which for output gives the seconds truncated to `0 <= n <= 6` decimal places (and if `%OS` is not followed by a digit, it uses the setting of `getOption("digits.secs")`, or if that is unset, `n = 0`).

Hence:

```r
for (i in c("", 0:9)) {
  format <- paste0("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", i, " %Z")
  cat(format(y, format = format), "\n")
}
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.1 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.12 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.123 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.1234 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.12345 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.123456 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.123456 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.123456 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.123456 EST 

for (i in c(list(NULL), 0:9)) {
  options(digits.secs = i)
  cat(format(y, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS %Z"), "\n")
}
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.1 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.12 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.123 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.1234 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.12345 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.123456 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.123456 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.123456 EST 
## 2022-01-21 19:55:26.123456 EST
```

Though, if you are going to set `digits.secs`, then there may be no need to call `format` yourself, as `print.POSIXct` does it for you:

```r
for (i in c(list(NULL), 0:9)) {
  options(digits.secs = i)
  print(y)
}
## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26 EST"
## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26 EST"
## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26.1 EST"
## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26.12 EST"
## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26.123 EST"
## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26.1234 EST"
## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26.12345 EST"
## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26.123456 EST"
## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26.123456 EST"
## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26.123456 EST"
## [1] "2022-01-21 19:55:26.123456 EST"
```